# Call to a member function removeElement() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I'm creating a form to be able to send an email message to a group of students which are linked to a particular course. By default all students for a given course must be selected, but the sender of the message must be able to deselect students to exclude them from receiving the message. Sending to the whole group is no problem. The problem occurs when removing students from the select.

I'm using Sonata Admin's sonata_type_model with a custom query. On the resulting form, if I don't change the select options and submit the form everything works fine. When I remove an item from the list I get an error after submitting the form:

Error: Call to a member function removeElement() on a non-object in /xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Model/ModelManager.php line 607

After two days of searching for an answer hopefully someone here can help me in the right direction. Here's some of the code I use:

Admin:

```
$em = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('Stnu\EduBundle\Entity\DealItem');
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->select('d')
            ->from('StnuEduBundle:DealItem', 'd')
            ->innerJoin('d.deal', 'de')
            ->where('d.course = :course')
            ->andWhere('de.status = :status')
            ->setParameter('course',$course)
            ->setParameter('status','order');

    $defaults = $query->getQuery()->getResult();


    $formMapper
            ->with('Certificaten verzenden cursus \''. $title .'\'', array('description' => 'Begeleidende tekst e-mail'))
                ->add('dealItems', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'expanded' => false,
                    'btn_add' => false,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'label' => 'Verzenden aan',
                    'query' => $query,
                    'property' => 'deal.user',
                    'data' => $defaults,
                    'validation_groups' => false
                ))
                ->add('subject', 'text', array('required' => true, 'label' => 'Onderwerp', 'data' => $subject))
                ->add('body', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Bericht', 'required' => false, 'data' => $body, 'attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce', 'data-theme' => 'fullpage', 'style' => 'height: 350px')));
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * Create action
 *
 * @return Response
 *
 * @throws AccessDeniedException If access is not granted
 */
public function createAction()
{

    // the key used to lookup the template
    $templateKey = 'edit';

    if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('CREATE')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    $object = $this->admin->getNewInstance();

    $this->admin->setSubject($object);


    /** @var $form \Symfony\Component\Form\Form */
    $form = $this->admin->getForm();
    $form->setData($object);


    if ($this->getRestMethod()== 'POST') {

        $object->setDealItems($object->getDealItems());

        $form->submit($this->get('request'));
```

The error appears right after this point.

Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Stnu\EduBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * DocsEmail
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CertificateEmail {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="DealItem")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="certificateemails_dealitems",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="certificateEmail_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="dealItem_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $dealItems;

    private $subject;

    private $body;

    private $extraEmailTo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dealItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add dealItem
     *
     */
    public function addDealItem(\Stnu\EduBundle\Entity\DealItem $dealItem) {

        $this->dealItems->add($dealItem);
        //$this->dealItems[] = $dealItem;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove dealItem
     */
    public function removeDealItem(\Stnu\EduBundle\Entity\DealItem $dealItem) {

        foreach ($this->dealItems as $item) {
            if ($dealItem === $item) {
                // manager of Stnu\EduBundle\Entity\DealItem
                $entityManager->remove($dealItem);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get dealItems
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getDealItems() {

        return $this->dealItems;
    }

    public function setDealItems($dealItems) {
        $this->dealItems = new ArrayCollection();

        if (count($dealItems) > 0) {
            foreach ($dealItems as $dealItem) {
                $this->addDealItem($dealItem);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Set subject
     *
     * @param string $subject
     */
    public function setSubject($subject) {
        $this->subject = $subject;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get subject
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSubject() {
        return $this->subject;
    }

    /**
     * Set body
     *
     * @param string $body
     */
    public function setBody($body) {
        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get body
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBody() {
        return $this->body;
    }

    /**
     * Set extraEmailTo
     *
     * @param string $extraEmailTo
     */
    public function setExtraEmailTo($extraEmailTo) {
        $this->extraEmailTo = $extraEmailTo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get extraEmailTo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getExtraEmailTo() {
        return $this->extraEmailTo;
    }

}
```

Hopefully someone can help me out!

Comment: The error suggests that _dealItems_ is null when _removeElement()_ is called.  I can see that you're initialising the collection when the object is constructed - so that seems to me to mean that somewhere along the line, _dealItems_ is destroyed ... but I can't see where

Comment: What's going on here - `$object->setDealItems($object->getDealItems());` ?

Comment: I guess just a test to see if it helps. I'll remove this code.

Comment: Dear Ragdata and Stijlnu! Thanks for my reputation ;)

Comment: This one is suspect too @Stijlnu - `$form->submit($this->get('request'));`  The Form class you've referenced in the comment above it (I do the same thing to help my IDE out) doesn't have a _submit_ method ... have you extended it?

Comment: I basically copied this code from the SonataAdmin CRUDcontroller, and modified it with some custom code. The original CRUDcontroller has this line too. In fact everything in the code up to this point comes from the original createAction in the CRUDcontroller.

Comment: I just read your comment about not needing to persist data from the email.  What about using that query you've got above to populate a simple 'choice' field type? [Choice Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)  If you don't need a full entity - I'm guessing you only need email addresses of students - this could be the way to go.  If you think this could help, let me know and I'll code up a sample.

Comment: Yes, that might work. I liked the layout of the sonata_type_collection.

Comment: @Ragdata I'm looking forward to your code sample. Meanwhile I'm still trying to find anything related to this on Google...

Comment: @Stijlnu - Yup, it's there ... check my updated answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is getting closer to an answer to your question.  The problem is, you asked ENTIRELY the wrong question.  The important stuff is below, under "EDIT - Custom Multiple Select Field".

Your `removeDealItem` method is all wrong.  Try this:

```
    public function removeDealItem(\Stnu\EduBundle\Entity\DealItem $dealItem)
    {
        $this->dealItems->removeElement( $dealItem );

        return $this;
    }
```

You don't HAVE an `$entityManager` to call on here ... and you don't need one.  Doctrine will check to see if the entity you want to remove exists, and remove it if it does.  You don't need to iterate over the existing elements in your collection, and you certainly don't need to do anything on a database level.

```
    public function addDealItem(\Stnu\EduBundle\Entity\DealItem $dealItem)
    {
        // Getting fancy - check if the item exists before adding it
        if( !$this->dealItems->contains($dealItem) )
        {
            $this->dealItems->add($dealItem);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Adding an item is just as easy ... we can even get fancy with it and use the Doctrine `ArrayCollection::contains()` method to check if an element exists before we add it.  There's nothing wrong with your `addDealItem()` method - I just wanted to show you `contains()` as a more visible illustration of letting the `ArrayCollection` class do the work for you.

**EDIT - Custom Multiple Select Field**

OK - after reading your comment about not necessarily needing to persist the data, I thought I'd offer this simplified example of how to create a custom multiple select box.  Please understand that this is a 'bare basics' example - but it SHOULD lead you in the right direction.  Obviously, without knowing the structure of your DealItem Entity I'm only GUESSING about the specific fields you need to access in order get the data you need to send your email.

So - **in your Controller** - first we get the data:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->select('d')
            ->from('StnuEduBundle:DealItem', 'd')
            ->innerJoin('d.deal', 'de')
            ->where('d.course = :course')
            ->andWhere('de.status = :status')
            ->setParameter('course',$course)
            ->setParameter('status','order');

$defaults = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

$choices = array();

foreach( $defaults as $dealItem )
{
    $choices[ $dealItem->getEmailAddress() ] = $dealItem->getStudentName();
}
```

Now we need an object to receive the data.  What I've gathered from your comments is that you don't want to persist the data, and that you only created an Entity for your CertificateEmail object so that you could build a form.  Bad idea.  **You don't need an entity - so don't build one in the first place.**  To prove a point, I'll do it with a stdClass object:

```
$certificateEmail = new \stdClass();

$certificateEmail->dealItems = array();
$certificateEmail->subject   = '';
$certificateEmail->body      = '';
```

Then we build the form:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder( $certificateEmail )
             ->add( 'dealItems', 'choice', array(
                         'choices'  => $choices,
                         'multiple' => true,
                         'required' => true,
                         'label'    => 'Verzenden aan' ) )
             ->add( 'subject', 'text', array( 'required' => true, 'label' => 'Onderwerp' ) )
             ->add( 'body', 'textarea', array( 'required' => false, 'label' => 'Bericht' ) )
             ->getForm();
```

Finally, throw it at a template:

```
return $this->render( 'template.html.twig', array( 'form' => $form->createView() ) );
```

And, hopefully, you can take it from there :)

Comment: _removeDealItem_ really did need to be fixed - but I'm starting to think that this is not where your problem lies..

Comment: As a test I just created a new Entity and form Admin class from scratch, without most of the custom coding. I just kept the custom query for the sonata_type_collection. This time I let it persist to the database. Same problem occurs. Persisting works fine only if I don't remove items from the select. Testing without the custom query won't work as I receive an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: @Stijlnu - give that updated answer a shot and let me know how you go

Comment: Well... I just figured out that if I remove the data attribute (hope I'm using the right terminology) from the formmapper, everything works fine. `//'data' => $defaults,`

Comment: ['data' Form Field Option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#data)

Comment: So, I guess I somehow need to provide de data option with a collection instead of an array. I'm looking into 'ArrayToModelTransformer' now.

Comment: You're overthinking this.  Do you need to persist the data?

Comment: I hate being close and not being able to solve it. That's why I still pursue a solution ;) The other thing is that I have another very similar form where I do need to persist the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the script sample. I think I will rewrite my code to be much cleaner. This certainly helps me in the right direction. I like many aspects of Symfony, but the learning curve is steep to me.

Comment: OK - so if you did need to persist it the answer would be slightly different.  I'd suggest that you use an 'entity' field type: [Entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).  I suspect that your perception that you are 'close' could be an illusion - there's a lot that has been said here tonight which suggests that you're way off the mark.  Pursuing the solution is indeed commendable.  But I IMPLORE you - forget Sonata for the moment.  Figure out how to do it with vanilla Symfony, and THEN re-introduce the additional complexity of Sonata.

Comment: YES !!  Symfony is steep enough.  Give yourself a break.  Uninstall ALL additional bundles, and add them once you have tackled the basics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions.

Comment: I was able to finally solve it by changing `$defaults = $query->getQuery()->getResult();` to `$defaults = new Collections\ArrayCollection($query->getQuery()->getResult());`

Answer (score 1):

Check your collection before delete action.

```
ldd($object->getDealItems()); // or var_dump();die();
```

I think when calls delete action your property **dealItems** is empty.

Comment: removeElement() is a method of Doctrine's _ArrayCollection_ class ... I don't think that's the problem here

Comment: When you create **NewInstance**. You use this `$object->setDealItems($object->getDealItems());`. Are you sure that `$object->getDealItems()` return collection when working delete?

Comment: I think $this->dealItems being collection indeed causes the problem. Unfortunately this suggestion didn't work for me. I tried putting echo 'test'; exit(); within this function to see if it ever reaches this point. It seems like it doesn't.

Comment: _dealItems_ HAS to be a collection - or your association will fall over

Comment: Try to use `preRemove($object)` or override `delete($object)` for checking `$object->getDealItems()`

Comment: No, I'm not sure $object->getDealItems() returns collection. Don't know how to check to be honest. How can I make sure it will be a collection?

Comment: Your constructor initialises _dealItems_ as an _ArrayCollection_ when the object is created.  Your _setDealItems()_ method ALSO initialises _dealItems_ as an _ArrayCollection_ (redundant, but not the problem). This is necessary for your association to work. I think it's HIGHLY unlikely that _dealItems_ is anything other than an _ArrayCollection_ seeing as though it's a private property of your Entity ...

Comment: Need more code ... it's not making a lot of sense right now.  Somehow, somewhere, something is managing to unset a _private_ property of your DealItem Entity ... which MUST happen somewhere in the Entity itself.

Comment: Do us a favour and post your entire Entity class

Comment: Would it help to post a var_dump of $object or $this->get('request')

Comment: The Entity class in its entirety would be better as a first step.  _$dealItems_ is private ... nothing else can interact with it directly.

Comment: I'd still like to know what the line `$object->setDealItems($object->getDealItems());` is meant to achieve as well. According to the code you've posted, it shouldn't _really_ matter as it looks as though it would result in an empty ArrayCollection object ... but it looks kinda suspect to me.

Comment: I removed this line $object->setDealItems($object->getDealItems());

Comment: I tried var_dump($object->getDealItems()); It indeed gives an empty result

Comment: @Stijlnu so, therefore problem because your object have not collection with dealItems

Comment: That really doesn't make sense to me - it's set TWICE in your Entity - once on object initialisation, and once when you execute the _setDealItems()_ method.  SOMETHING in your Entity class MUST be un-setting it ... it's a private property.

Comment: @Stijlnu try to test your object which have deal items. For example, in createAction(): `var_dump($certificateEmailManager->find($id)->getDealItems());  die();`.

Comment: I updated my question with the full code of the Entity

Comment: OK - I still can't really see the problem at hand ... but I can see a couple of problems with the Entity.  I'll write it up as an answer so that you can see the code easier ... but it's not REALLY going to be an answer ... just a tic

Comment: @Danilla this var_dump results in: Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Comment: @Stijlnu `var_dump($this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('certification_email_manage_id_HERE')->find(id_record_which_have_deal_items_HERE)->getDealItems()); die();`

Comment: @Stijlnu I don't know it is your project)) I think id of manager somewhere in xml/yaml config file. Id record in your db.

Comment: @Stijlnu hey! Do you find id's?

Comment: I'm not really sure what to look for. I have an admin.yml which has sonata.admin.certificateEmail as an entry. That might be the 'certification_emai‌​l_manage_id_HERE'. Now I'm searching for the other one...

Comment: @Stijlnu [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html) about id of service.

Comment: @Stijlnu or you can get it something like that: `$em = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('Stnu\EduBundle\Entity\CertificateEmail');`.

Comment: In my db I just have one record named Id for this table.

Comment: @Stijlnu You must be sure that when you get CertificationEmai‌​l from db and when you calls `->getDealItems()` will returned collection of objects DealItem. After you need to test manager. Try to delete some DealItem using manager. If all steps is true => problem with sonata else => problems with relations, entities or something else.

Comment: @Stijlnu I know that in last versions sonata admin have not problems with many-to-many. But in oldest versions it was necessary to add something.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid persisting the CertificationEmail to the db. I'm using the entity just to be able to generate the form with the students related to a course preset. Once the mail is sent, I don't need to keep record of it. Maybe I'm not using the right way of programming this functionality within Symfony/SonataAdmin.